# after applied patch 8788 in Magento V. 1.9.0.0 admin product image browse files not working

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, uploader

I have applied patch 3941 and after that I have applied patch 8788 but when in admin product try to select image see following steps

```
-> I click on Browse Files... 
-> It opens a dialog box and then 
-> I select the image and click on Open
```

it takes few minute and it shows me error like below image[image]

Why does this happen? if i revert patch 8788 its working fine.

Note: It is working fine in safari browser.
 Not working in chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue, Spent 2 two days solving it but did not succeed, Checked so many posts but nothing has solve me.

Comment: @KaushalSuthar Nope, I just revert the patch also I spent much time but didn't get any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

please check below files if it is there then delete it manually

```
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

I think this could be only possible error for your problem.

you can read this thing in below url to

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930security-upgrade

Comment: yeah .swf files are deleted